# p tags breaking out of div body

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="recipe" id="1">
      <img src="https://www.biggerbolderbaking.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1C5A9329.jpg" class="recipe-logo" />
      <p class="item-1">Chocolate Brownies</p>
      <p class="item-2">24/11/2019</p>
      <p class="item-3">Prep Time: 20mins</p>
      <p class="item-4">Cook Time: 30mins</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

with the following CSS attached

```
.recipe {
  background-color: white;
  height: 250px;
}
.recipe-logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```css
.recipe {
  background-color: white;
  height: 250px;
}

.recipe-logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="recipe" id="1">
    <img src="https://www.biggerbolderbaking.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1C5A9329.jpg" class="recipe-logo" />
    <p class="item-1">Chocolate Brownies</p>
    <p class="item-2">24/11/2019</p>
    <p class="item-3">Prep Time: 20mins</p>
    <p class="item-4">Cook Time: 30mins</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to have a sideway list that looks something like this

[image]

however, even though I have the wrapper div ('recipe') set to only have a height of 250px, the `<p>` tags break out of the div, and form a vertical list below it, so I get this

[image]

Comment: Add `float: left;` to `.recipe-logo` selector.

Comment: Take a look to css Grid or Flexbox . It allows you to set a perfect layout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: You can easily solve this by using bootstrap. Once you understand it, it would open a world for you. Pleasse look at the quick course about bootstrap on w3schools, it will be benefit you development skills

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not need and does not use a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you need more styles to add **flexbox**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="recipe" id="1">
      <img src="https://www.biggerbolderbaking.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1C5A9329.jpg" class="recipe-logo" />
   <div class="p_wrapper">
      <p class="item-1">Chocolate Brownies</p>
      <p class="item-2">24/11/2019</p>
      <p class="item-3">Prep Time: 20mins</p>
      <p class="item-4">Cook Time: 30mins</p>
    </div>
   <div>
</div>



.recipe{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.p_wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap items into another div and change recipe display to flex.

```css
.recipe {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  height: 250px;
}
.recipe-logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="recipe" id="1">
    <img src="https://www.biggerbolderbaking.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1C5A9329.jpg" class="recipe-logo" />
    <div>
      <p class="item-1">Chocolate Brownies</p>
      <p class="item-2">24/11/2019</p>
      <p class="item-3">Prep Time: 20mins</p>
      <p class="item-4">Cook Time: 30mins</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your `img` and `div` to be in `display: inline-block`. It allows you to display items side-by-side instead of vertically. *One common use for it is with list items.*

**Here is an example:**

```css
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://store.playstation.com/store/api/chihiro/00_09_000/container/FR/fr/999/EP0149-CUSA09988_00-AV00000000000001/1553560094000/image?w=100&h=100&bg_color=000000&opacity=100&_version=00_09_000" alt="img" />
<div id="content">
  <h2>Chocolate Brownies</h2>
  <div>24/11/2019</div>
  <div>Prep time: 20mins</div>
  <div>Cook time: 30mins</div>
</div>
```